# by VB.Net, is it possible to exclusively access(write files) to USB connected external storage?

Tags: .net, vb.net, driver, usb-drive

For a security reason, I want to copy local computer files to external USB storage(eg: USB flash drive or hard drive) exclusively.

It means, the user cannot access the USB storage via Explorer, and the user cannot run and copy any file on the USB drive.

But, through the 'Program', the user can copy files from the local computer to the USB storage, and the user can see the directory structure.

In summary, is it possible to make a program that has exclusive access permission(privilege) to USB-connected external storage?

Does it need DRIVER-thing?

VB.Net is preferred, but any other language can be good.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make a program that has exclusive access permission(privilege) to USB-connected external storage?

The best option would be to create your own Save Dialog, which contains a tree view, only showing the removable drives and their contents for the user to save to:

```
Dim saveFileDialog As New System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog()
saveFileDialog.CustomPlaces.Clear()
saveFileDialog.CustomPlaces.Add(AddGuidOfTheExternalDriveOneByOne)
...
saveFileDialog.ShowDialog()
```

And this is how you list the drives that are tagged as "removable drive":

```
Dim ListDrives As DriveInfo() = DriveInfo.GetDrives()

For Each Drive As DriveInfo In ListDrives
    If Drive.DriveType = DriveType.Removable Then
        Add to RemovableDrive list or somethiing
    End If
Next
```

Comment: that would not be a solution because the user can access the removable drives through Explorer, My Computer and also any other software. I want to block users to access through any other software except my program.